# Error al querer mostrar datos de Firebase + Vuejs + ElectronJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, vue.js, electron

No puedo ver datos con electronJs y Vuejs desde Firebase.

```
let usuarios = mdb.ref("usuarios");
var vm = this;   
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var userid = "";
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        userid = user.uid
        console.log("ID : " + user.uid);
        console.log("EMAIL : " + user.email);
        console.log("userid : " + userid);
        var usuariosdata = mdb.ref("usuarios").child(userid);        
        console.log("usuariosdata : " + usuariosdata);
    } else {
        console.log("ES totalemente nulo")
        var usuariosdata = null 
    }
});
```

Desde `console.log` dentro de `onAuthStateChanged` puedo ver por consola los datos del usuario, pero cuando intento ejecutar `console.log` desde afuera de `onAuthStateChanged` me muestra un dato nulo. ¿Por qué?

`usuariosdata` es la referencia que necesito para mostrar mis datos.

Answer (score 1):

Eso es porque Firebase solo pasa el parámetro user dentro de la misma función, si lo que quieres es mostrar los datos del usuario actual, coloca la siguiente variable dentro de las funciones en las que necesites estos datos:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

Y lo puedes utilizar dentro de cada función declarándolo dentro de la misma o puedes hacerlo global. Como en los siguientes ejemplos (en este caso representado en JQuery):

```
$("mietiqueta").on("click", function(){
 var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
 console.log(user.uid);
});
```

O

```
var USER = firebase.auth().currentUser;
$("mietiqueta").on("click", function(){
 console.log(USER.uid);
});
```

En la función `onAuthStateChanged(user)` como ya mencione, lo puedes hacer gracias al parámetro de esta, pero para hacerlo en otro sitio solo basta con usar la instancia necesaria de Firebase Auth en el lugar donde lo quieres utilizar.

Te dejo aquí: [Obtén el perfil de un usuario - Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?hl=es-419#get_a_users_profile)

Espero haberme explicado bien y que te sea de ayuda.

> **EDIT:**

Si lo que quieres en cambio es introducir o mostrar los datos de tu DB, cabe destacar que previo los debes de haber guardado, de otra forma te va a devolver null porque no existe tal dato en la base de datos.

Una pequeña guía seria la siguiente:

> Guarda los datos de tus usuarios en la base de datos.

Aquí guardamos los datos dentro del nodo `users/uidDelUsuario`

```
//Crea la referencia a la base de datos 
var db = firebase.database();
//Crea una referencia con el uid del usuario.
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var userId = user.uid;
//Crea una referencia al lugar en donde quieres almacenar con el id 
//correspondiente
db.ref("users/"+userId).set({
 Nombre: user.displayName,
 Id: user.uid,
 etc...
});
```

Ya tenemos los datos del usuario almacenados en la base de datos.

> Requerimos los datos del usuario en nuestra interface (consola).

Aquí llamamos los datos que están dentro del nodo `users/uidDelUsuario`

```
//Usamos las referencias de la misma manera
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var userId = user.uid;
var db = firebase.database();
// Solicitamos los datos de la base de datos con una snapshot
db.ref("users/"+userId).on("value", function(snapshot){
 //Utilizamos nuestra snapshot de la siguiente manera
 console.log(snapshot.val())
 //O
 var data = snapshot.val();
 console.log(data.Nombre);
 console.log(data.Id);
 etc...
});
```

Aquí te dejo: [Lee y escribe datos en la Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?hl=es-419)

Nuevamente espero sea de ayuda, los contenidos los puedes encontrar mas completos en la documentación dentro de los enlaces que te he dejado.

Comment: Gracias por tu increible respuesta! pero no he podido solucionar mi problema. Sigo sin poder usar a la variable user fuera de onAuthStateChanged. Cuendo quiero colocar uid usando user.uid me dice que la propiedad o metodo uid no esta reconocido. Me estoy rompiendo la cabeza pero no encuetro la solucion por que no puedo realizar la referencia. Estoy a punto de cambiar a MongoDB

Comment: Que raro, tienes todos tus scripts de Firebase colocados antes que el script donde estas trabajando y después del body? La verdad es que Firebase es mucho mejor, si quieres otra alternativa te sugiero [RethinkDB](https://www.rethinkdb.com/)  también seria bueno observar como estas implementando Firebase y en que orden.

Comment: Para saber si estas colocando todo en orden, declarando la configuración 
, inicializando la app de Firebase correctamente, etc. Si puedo ayudarte mas seria un gusto.

Comment: Si estoy llamando al archivo js despues del body. Cuando lo coloco en el head tengp problema con vuejs por que me reconoce el nombre del  elemento de la app. Ejemplo: la aplicacion comienza con un <div id="app"> content </div> y me muestra un error que no puede encontrar el elemento app, esto pasa cuando coloco el link a vuejs en el head

Comment: Entiendo, cuando estas en tu documento .js inicializas la aplicación de Firebase con tu configuración?  algo como: `firebase.initializeApp(config);` también seria bueno declarar las variables de tus instancias de firebase despues de esto ej: `var auth = firebase.auth();`